# Can't center an ul inside a div. Tried many things

Tags: css

The navigation bar at top contains `width: 100% height: 50px` and is fixed positioned to the top.

However, the UL tag inside is always keeps positioning itself to the left side. It should be centered.

I tried so many things, like making a secondary div and giving it `margin: 0 auto`, giving
UL  `margin: 0 auto`, making `left %30` and `right %30`, `float: center` etc.

Am I missing something? What's the reason I can't position it to the center?

Comment: Could you create a [short and working example](http://sscce.org/) and post the code in your question? That way, when you fix your site, this question may still be of value to future users. (Note that you can edit your question to add details.)

Comment: Thought about this, but the sources were pretty long.

Comment: Have you read the link in my comment? It explains how to create a *short* example. Like I said, without a way to reproduce the problem based on your question, the question is not useful to anyone else in the future (which is kind-of the point for SO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On '#navlist' change text-align: left to be text-align: center

On '#navlist ul' add the property display: inline-block;

Comment: Thank you so much! I would like to ask though, why didn't use things like margin and just an inline-block?

Comment: You could probably remove the text-align property from #navlist altogether and it would work with just display: inline-block and auto margins on the UL. Please upvote my answer and accept it when you are able to. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a div that wraps the ul and set its margin to "0px auto" just like you tried with the ul.

```
<div style="width:600px; margin:0px auto;">
     <ul>...</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set and width for the Navigation bar, so it can be centered.

```
#menu-main-nav {
    width: 990px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make that div with some fix width and float. left or right. 
then inside it..  make UL and with property of margin:0 auto;

```
div {
    width:200px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}

ul {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had good luck centering a UL with these styles:

```
<style>
#container {text-align:center;}
#container ul {display:inline;}
#container ul li {display:inline;list-style-type:none;}
</style>
```

Generally, I have to steer clear of display:inline-block as we still develop for older IE browsers that don't acknowledge 'inline-block'.